# How to reload storage when login success ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, storage

I create sidemenu and I set show image after user login success.

But I get Error because when after login success sidemenu not show username and image(get data.json),If refresh app sidemenu show username and image.

example

[Before user login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVGTY.png)

[After user login success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaAib.png)

when refresh app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrii0.png)

I want to reload storage when user login success

Comment: Could you please add to the post the most relevant parts of the code?

Comment: it long text  cannot post it ,Can you create discussion between you and me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Events**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/).

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to application-level events across your app.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

// first page (publish an event when a user is created)
function createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}

// second page (listen for the user created event)
events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
  // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
  console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
});
```

In your case, you can save data from JSON to [localstorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.9/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/) inside  `events.publish` in for example login.ts, and then access it in app.component.ts inside `events.subscribe`

Comment: I got it! thank you very much . I can not vote post you. my reputation less than 15 for vote. sorry